# Android room compiler error when trying to return a list of own objects in the DAO: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int

Tags: sql, database, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using room for database operations. I have a class TableQuestion which holds a string and a id and I have a class TableAnswer which holds a string, an id plus the id of the question where it is refering to. QuizTask brings together the Question with all its answers. The query getQuestionsWithAnswer should return a QuizTask which wraps the question with all its answers. The error metioned in the title happens in auto-generated code of room.

The relevant part of the interface:

```
@android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
public interface dbDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT table_question.question, table_answer.answer FROM    table_question, table_answer WHERE table_question.id = table_answer.id_question")
    LiveData<List<QuizTask>> getQuestionsWithAnswers();
}
```

Class TableQuestion:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = TableQuestionnaire.class,
        parentColumns = "id",
        childColumns = "id_questionnaire",
        onDelete = CASCADE),
        tableName = "table_question")
public class TableQuestion {
    @PrimaryKey
    public final int id;

    @NonNull
    public String question;

    @NonNull
    public int id_questionnaire;

    public String subject;

    public String category;

    public String sub_category;

    @Ignore
    public String questionnaire;

    public TableQuestion(int id, @NonNull String question, int  id_questionnaire, String subject, String category, String sub_category) {
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.id_questionnaire = id_questionnaire;
        this.questionnaire = null;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.category = category;
        this.sub_category = sub_category;
    }

    public void setQuestionnaire(String questionnaire){
        this.questionnaire = questionnaire;
    }
}
```

Class TableAnswer:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = TableQuestion.class,
        parentColumns = "id",
        childColumns = "id_question",
        onDelete = CASCADE),
        tableName = "table_answer")
public class TableAnswer {
    @PrimaryKey
    public final int id;

    @NonNull
    public String answer;

    @NonNull
    public final int id_question;

    public boolean rightAnswer;

    public TableAnswer(int id, String answer, int id_question, boolean rightAnswer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.id_question = id_question;
        this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    }
}
```

Class QuizTask:

```
public class QuizTask {
    @Embedded
    private TableQuestion question;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "id_question")
    private List<TableAnswer> answers;

    public void setQuestion(TableQuestion question){ this.question = question; }

    public TableQuestion getQuestion(){
        return question;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<TableAnswer> answers) { this.answers = answers; }

    public List<TableAnswer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }
}
```

AndroidStudio doesn't show any error upon compilation. When room auto-generates the code for getQuestionWithAnswers it shows a compiler error "incompatible types:  cannot be converted to int". In the auto-generated dbDao_Impl.java is a row where a TableQuestion object is tried to create but with null for the id parameter. That's where the error occurs. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

```
@Query("SELECT table_question.question, table_answer.answer FROM    table_question, table_answer WHERE table_question.id = table_answer.id_question")
```

There is no id selected but used later on. That's why room tries to create objects with Id = null which is not possible. So simply change to:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_question, table_answer WHERE table_question.id = table_answer.id_question")
```